# Django backend with Android

Tags: java, android, django-rest-framework, aws-sdk

To start I must request to not close this as broad question.The question is to make a backend on aws and connect it with Android. I have been working with Android for quite some time now but I have not yet got any leads on how to share stuff from one device to other (photo shraing app). Can anyone please tell me the steps to start with it or any helpful links

Comment: Hi Tejasw. How will sharing happen? NFC, Bluetooth? Or users will upload photos to your server and then share over the internet?

Comment: Well, sorry, but it is indeed "a broad question"

Comment: @Mehmed it would happen to server , take this like your device uploads pictures and data to a server say mysql running on AWS using Django api and the other device receives it using get request.

Comment: @yeya then for you I should narrow it down to using Django to make an api for connecting android to a aws db(Cassandra)

Comment: [ask], How did you try to solve the issue by yourself?